# SonarQube Plugin and TI Code Composer 5

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, code-composer

I am currently working on a TI Microcontroller platform using Code Composer 5.5 as the IDE.  Our code baseline is analyzed by SonarQube to produce metrics and issue identification against a set of rules and standards.

SonarQube website mention support for Eclipse via a plugin.  Since Code Composer 5 is Eclipse based I was able to install it but I cannot finish the configuration by linking the project as described.  When I right click on the project in the Project Explorer there is no option to Configure then Associate with SonarQube.

Is there a way to make this menu option show or a command line method to make this association?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, only projects with the following 'nature' can be associated with SonarQube:

- Java (JDT) Project
- C/C++ (CDT) Project
- Pydev Project

If your TI Code Composer projects do not have one of these natures, you won't be able to associate them (at least with the current version of the Eclipse SonarQube Plugin).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299105/tell-sonarsource-that-so-is-not-a-bug-tracker

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the pointer to meta - although in this case this question seems to me a legit case of a user asking for help on a very specific subject, which can be useful to other users of Code Composer and SonarQube. I have forwarded the meta link to the relevant people at SonarSource.

Answer (score 1):

Got help from our friends at TI E2E forums on this topic.

The reason I was unable to see the Configure and Associate menu options was due to the selected perspective.  Code Composer 5 uses TI's default CCS Edit perspective which hides the expected menu options.  If you change to the default Eclipse C/C++ perspective then the menu option shows up and configuration of the project to use SonarQube can be completed.